# Rasterizing with target in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, rasterization

With QGIS 2.18, the "rasterize" command offered the possibility of defining a raster target. I used this option to "update" a existing raster with the value of a polygon layer.

I'm not able anymore to find this possibility in QGIS 3.2. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented by @Kazuhito:](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292703/qgis-3-2-rasterize-with-a-target/321809#comment469608_292703)

> QGIS 3.2 does not allow you to use a raster file as a target. However,
>   once you add the raster file as a layer in your project, it can be
>   used to define the extent of the output (by selecting `Use
>   layer/canvas extent`).  This applies also to QGIS 2.18 when Rasterize
>   is activated from the processing toolbox.